# preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures is not called

Tags: ios

https://github.com/Antidote-for-Tox/Antidote/

When I override `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` in the view controller that is embedded in a tab bar controller, the function is not called.

Comment: Have you added delegate into you viewController?

Comment: This is open source code, not what I wrote.Because I am not very familiar with the code, I can't locate the problem. Do you know one of the reasons for not calling 'preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures'?

Answer (score 1):

Because a new UIWindow is created in the code, and 'isHidden' is set to false, the rewritten 'childViewControllerForScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures' is not called in the UITabbarcontroller, and the viewcontroller in its viewcontrollers does not call the rewritten 'preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures'. I know his production, but I don't know the real reason. Because when I block the window code or 'isHidden = false', there will be no problem.
In short, the new Window affects the call of system functions.